# How to mass change with sapui5 sap.ui.table.Table and large amount of data?

Tags: sapui5

I am searching for a way to mass change a column of a very big table with sap.ui.table.Table. Unforunately it is used in the SmartTable control which also handles the paging.

I am loading the numbers of the selected lines with .getSelectedIndices().
This works also for a larg amount of data, say several thousands of lines.

Anyhow the data is never fully loaded on the frontend. Also it would be hard to do so. For a hacky solution I would do so but can't find a good way.

Question 1):
For a hack, how could I force to load all data. Imaging there is a smartfilterbar and a smarttable around and the paging is managed.

Question 2):
The clean solution should be a function import. Anyhow for this I need to ensure the the backend would sort an "internal" table the same way as the frontend would do so that the selected index stuff works correct.

Question 3):
Or is there a better solution for mass chaning data with user line picking and potential complex filtering?

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about a select-all type scenario where not all data is loaded?

Comment: A change all but with "selected" values. Assume you tick select all and unselect some of them. So you have just a list of line numbers of the table. And this list could be a large one. So point is, that the filter allone does not define the set to change.

Comment: the issue with that logic though is that in a sense the "invisible" rows have not been reviewed and therefore not necessarily have been unselected. you can really only say that the visible lines have been reviewed in that regard, no? otherwise, it would be 'use the entire selection, except for the unchecked rows which have been seen by the user'

Comment: Yes, unselection only works with loaded data. But the mentioned SAPUI5 Table lists also the line index of unloaded data. In that case you have just a list of lines of a table - but not neccassary the corresponding data, and not eaven the path to load the data. So user could select "all" and just unselect the first three. Could be a stupid use case but it would be possible. This is possible because the table knows the data "count" from the beginning.

Comment: If I could change the workflow that a combination of filters defines  the set to for the mass change is there a way to send the filters and the property to change to OData without loading everything? A kind of update_entity_set? Or still is the only way a function import? Would there be a standard way to send filters to the backend as a parameter?

Comment: There is a way to mass change lines but it relies on you sending all the lines, which you can only do if they were preloaded... You can try looking into the code that creates the filter string: `ODataUtils.createFilterParams(aFilters, this.oModel.oMetadata, this.oEntityType);`. There are classes in the gateway that convert that into ABAP filters but you'll need to hit that up in the debugger I'm afraid